# Problems Setting Up Remote Wordpress Site on Local Wamp

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

New to php and wordpress. Trying to set up one my website on my machine. Local WAMP server is running fine. I have another website running on it. This website was a fresh installation of wordpress on my local. But this other website that I'm trying to setup (downloaded files from server) loads the home page but I cannot access admin and any other pages e.g when I try to access admin I get redirected to

```
http://jfr.local/wp-admin/jfr.local/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fjfr.local%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

jfr.local is my local website setup as virtual host on WAMP. I already imported website and had to change site url in wp-options table because initially nothing was working. But now I don't know what I need to to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: "http://jfr.local/wp-admin/jfr.local/" looks like perhaps you have specified the url in the database incorrectly - maybe it's doing a relative url from where it is?    Probably both  your 'home' and 'siteurl' options in the database should be "http://jfr.local/"  ? Also check you don't have anything in your wp-config.php that may be overriding the settings in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out. Issue was that "http" was missing in the url in wp-options table. After this change I could log into admin but other pages on the site were still not showing. I read somewhere that by visiting each page within admin the permalinks get re-created. So that is what I did and all pages started showing after this. So seems like everything is working fine right now.